# rake assets:precompile compiling everything twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm having some trouble with Rails assets pre-compilation that I've never come across before. When running `rake assets:precomile` in this app I'm seeing every asset getting compiled twice. If I tail production.log I can see that it basically seems to be running the whole command twice in a row. Here's a modified sample from the logs...

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Compiled jquery.js  (97ms)  (pid 56296)
Compiled jquery.cycle.all.js  (2ms)  (pid 56296)
Compiled jquery.numeric.js  (0ms)  (pid 56296)
Compiled matchMedia.js  (0ms)  (pid 56296)
Compiled fastclick.js  (1ms)  (pid 56296)
... etc ...
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Compiled jquery.js  (97ms)  (pid 56296)
Compiled jquery.cycle.all.js  (2ms)  (pid 56296)
Compiled jquery.numeric.js  (0ms)  (pid 56296)
Compiled matchMedia.js  (0ms)  (pid 56296)
Compiled fastclick.js  (1ms)  (pid 56296)
... etc ...
```

Checking the compiled files confirms that it has compiled everything twice so all of the CSS & JS is duplicated.

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 2.0.0-p0 (also tried with 1.9.3-p392).

I've never had any issues with assets pre-compilation before so if anyone has any ideas on why it's exhibiting this unusual behaviour this time I'd love to hear it.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you maybe list your `config/application.rb`? What version of Rails are you using? Have you recently upgraded your Rails installation?

Comment: Using Rails 3.2.13. I have upgraded it a couple of times throughout the app's development but I've checked `config/application.rb` and all of the environment files against a fresh Rails 3.2.13 project and it doesn't look like I'm missing anything. `config/application.rb` can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/alistairholt/f4b1123c8c30aa03fe4e (removed a few sensitive things). Thanks.

Comment: Line 35 sets all the assets that need to be precompiled. I assume the multiple occasions of "sites/REMOVED.css" originate from different files?

Comment: Yup, they're all different files. I just removed the names for privacy.

Comment: Are you very sure this behaviour never happened before? I just ran the precompile of a 3.2.13 app of myself, and in fact some files appeared 5 times in the log. Maybe that is just the inner workings of the assets pipeline; it must hit each file multiple times?

Comment: I've never encountered it in any other projects but this is the first time I'm coming to precompiling the assets in this project. I wouldn't be worried about if it was just the logs that were showing duplicates but the compiled files themselves actually contain two copies of all the JS or CSS so I'm getting things like JS code running twice which is a problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29757/discussion-between-flaxfield-and-alistairholt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain a bit more about alistairholt's "gotcha": when running `rake assets:precompile` the assets are precompiled and placed in `public/assets`. It turns out this gives conflicts when loading the web app in the development environment, because it serves both the files from `public/assets` and the assets from the `app/assets` folder.